# RecyclerView GridLayoutManager scrolls down when inserting at top

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview

I've got a fragment that fills the screen with a `RecyclerView` (`android:support:v7.widget.RecyclerView`) and a `GridLayoutManager`. Support library version is *23.0.0*.

Let's say I've got **three** items per row. When I insert three new items at the top I'd expect everything to move down by one row. If I was at the very top I'd expect everything to move down by one row and to see my three new items in the very first row. Instead the View stays on the item. The new items get inserted but I've got to scroll up to see them. I wouldn't even recognize that something's changed unless I'd scrolled up.

**How can I achieve that everything moves down (i. e. it scrolls up or stays on the same index (which shifts)) by the number of inserted items?**

Here's how I insert new items:

```
myImageAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, batch.size());
```

Initialization:

```
final RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1);
grid = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid);
grid.setHasFixedSize(true)
grid.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
grid.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);
```

My `myImageAdapter` is a derivate of `RecyclerView.Adapter<?>` but nothing special.

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to achieve. Please tell me if not and I'll create a graphic to illustrate.

// addition from the `GridLayoutManager` docs: *"stackFromEnd is not supported by GridLayoutManager."* Seems like I can't use this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scrollToPosition()` property;

```
if(yourCurrentPosition < 3)
    layoutManager.scrollToPosition(0);
else
    layoutManager.scrollToPosition(yourCurrentPosition - 3);
```

In your activity/fragment you can use a data set observer:

```
myImageAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        super.onItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount);
        if(positionStart < 3)
            layoutManager.scrollToPosition(0);
        else
            layoutManager.scrollToPosition(positionStart - 3);
    }
});
```

Comment: When to call this? How do I keep track of the current position? It's rather a method than a property ;)

Comment: Alright but how do I keep track of my current position? Or ain't I have to? And what if the user is within a scrolling action?

Comment: @m02ph3u5 you haven't to take track of your current position because this method will notify where the change happened

Comment: It notifies where it happened but not where I currently am. But I'll need that information to calculate the delta.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager

public void scrollToPosition (int position)
```

example:

```
layoutManager.scrollToPosition(0);
```

after you add items.

Comment: You think I should count the number of items I inserted, keep track of my current position and then, upon insertion, scroll up? Can you provide a full example?